# How to fix dependency issue during package installation?

Tags: npm, dependency-management, craco

I'm trying to install [CRACO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco?activeTab=readme) in the project. I currently have `"typescript": "^5.3.2"` installed. When I try to install `CRACO` I get error:

```
npm i -D @craco/craco                     
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"*" from @storybook/react@7.5.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@storybook/react
npm ERR!     @storybook/react@"7.5.3" from @storybook/nextjs@7.5.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/nextjs
npm ERR!       dev @storybook/nextjs@"^7.0.22" from the root project
npm ERR!     @storybook/react@"7.5.3" from @storybook/preset-react-webpack@7.5.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/preset-react-webpack
npm ERR!       @storybook/preset-react-webpack@"7.5.3" from @storybook/nextjs@7.5.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@storybook/nextjs
npm ERR!         dev @storybook/nextjs@"^7.0.22" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">= 4.x" from @storybook/react-docgen-typescript-plugin@1.0.6--canary.9.0c3f3b7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@storybook/react-docgen-typescript-plugin
npm ERR!     @storybook/react-docgen-typescript-plugin@"1.0.6--canary.9.0c3f3b7.0" from @storybook/preset-react-webpack@7.5.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/preset-react-webpack
npm ERR!       @storybook/preset-react-webpack@"7.5.3" from @storybook/nextjs@7.5.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@storybook/nextjs
npm ERR!         dev @storybook/nextjs@"^7.0.22" from the root project
npm ERR!   11 more (eslint-config-next, fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   peer react-scripts@"^5.0.0" from @craco/craco@7.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@craco/craco
npm ERR!     dev @craco/craco@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     peer react-scripts@"^5.0.0" from @craco/craco@7.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@craco/craco
npm ERR!       dev @craco/craco@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

At the `CRACO` package I found `devDependency` `"typescript": "^4.8.4"`, which ideally shouldn't cause problems, since my typescript is newer. So why is it complaining? I can try and force installation or use `--legacy-peer-deps`, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.